# Unresolved external symbol with openCV

Tags: opencv, depth, openni

I'm trying to initialize OpenNI sensors using OpenCV in order to get depth map from depth sensor of my kinect.

The [code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html) I used to get one depth image:

and The output I get:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdelc cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) reference in function _main
```

In the `.pro` file I have:

```
QT += widgets
WITH_OPENNI = ON
```

Comment: you've got an unresolved external symbol, are you sure you have all your includes?

Comment: This is not an include but a linking error. You are missing some library (don't know which though)

Comment: Its highgui library that you are missing..

Comment: solved! I edited CMake.txt and now OpenCV can be recognized. Thank you, it was, as you said, a missing library